# Apply Filter Access 2010 with NULL not working

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010, office-2010

I have an Access 2010 database that has been migrated from 2003. I have a report that pulls data from a SQL backend and then in the Report_Open event filters that based on a value in a form using the DoCmd.ApplyFilter in VBA.

My filter query works fine and I get results, but as soon as I specify to give me where a field is null it crashes.

Below is the string that is passed into the filter query

```
    lclFilter = "(StartDate < '31 Mar 2013') AND (SalesTransactionDate <> '31 Mar 2013' OR SalesTransactionDate Is Null)"
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , lclFilter
```

Any help would be appreciated. This works if I remove the statement "or SalesTransactionDate Is Null" Otherwise I get nothing returned, not even an error message.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use MSAccess built-in function instead:

```
... OR IsNull(SalesTransactionDate)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as now all I get returned are all records.

Comment: can you add `StartDate` and `SalesTransactionDate` to the data grid and check what values are there